# Python Sphinx: remove external modules documentation

Tags: python, kivy, python-sphinx

I'm learning Sphinx and I'm having an issue.

This is a simplified version of my Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class MyApp(App):
    """
    Description.
    
    Attributes
    ----------
    layout : FloatLayout
        the widget returned in the build method
    string : StringProperty
        Some ´string´.
    """
    
    string = StringProperty("")
    
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        self.string = kwargs.get("string", "")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.layout = FloatLayout()
    
    
    def build(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I have to specify `string` as a class attribute, to make everything work in the more complex code.

This is the `conf.py` file:

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

project = 'Name'
copyright = '2023, Abel'
author = 'Abel'
release = '1.0'

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.napoleon', 'sphinx_mdinclude']

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

And the `index.rst` file:

```
.. Name documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Sat Jun 10 13:14:22 2023.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Name's documentation!
================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
   
   modules



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

When I run `.\make.bat html`, the documentation about `MyApp` is:

[image]

As you can see `string` is repeated twice, the second with the `kivy` documentation. I want to only show my docstring documentation, removing the entry added automatically from `kivy`

**EDIT**

This is the `modules.rst` file:

```
error
=====

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   main
```

**EDIT**

This is the `main.rst` file:

```
main module
===========

.. automodule:: main
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What is in modules.rst?

Comment: See edits, please.

Comment: And in main.rst, I suppose that you have `.. automodule:: main` (with the `:members:` option)?

Comment: Yes, I have. I added the file to the question.

Comment: As your class is a descendent of App, it apparently already has a `string` attribute - what exactly is the reason you're not using that attribute, but are defining a new one with the same name? Wouldn't it make more sense not to break any behaviour that depends on an `App` having the original attribute and use the value of that as you need?

Comment: `App` doesn't have a `string` attribute according to Kivy documentation.